# Should I use mysql for scalability?

Tags: php, mysql, database, oracle

I'm in the planning phase for developing a web application and am trying to figure out my best bet as far database options goes. I'm already familiar with php and mysql database. Initially, the website won't be handling any transactions, but my hope is that the website will expand to a large degree and I'll incorporate transactions and sales on the website. My concern is, will php be secure enough for the future transactions? If not, will it be possible to switch from mysql to maybe.. Oracle or another "more secure database" while the is expanding? Thanks for your time and responses.

Comment: "mysql vs oracle" for me looks like "prius vs bentley" (in terms of cupporting cost)

Comment: [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/)

Comment: Haha, I know. I guess I need to venture out of comfort zone and start looking into Oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plan for the foreseeable future and not beyond. If utilized correctly MySQL can scale incredibly well (just check out some of the names that use it http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/case-studies/ ).

As for the security aspect, that's totally up to your coding ability. Security is not inherently better in one language or DB over another, but certain languages have a very low barrier to entry (PHP being one of them) so they tend to invite many hobby programmers who develop applications that scale badly and are security nightmares.

Stick to what you know and let your technology develop as required. Most web apps that end up seriously scaling have a few rewrites in their history (often changing DB engines, frameworks, platforms, languages...). You can't predict the future, so stick to what you're good at now.

tl;dr: PHP and MySQL will be fine.

Comment: Scotty can also check out Amazon RDS for managed MySql in the cloud that should also help put to rest any scalability concerns.

Comment: well said and good points. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Php & MySQL are used in millions of commercial / transactional sites around the world. Security-wise, it is no less secure than any other language out there.

Switching to Oracle is also not a problem, though I fail to understand why one would be eager dive into those * *cough cough* * licensing fees that it comes with.

Comment: Indeed, that's another reason I've been reluctant to make the switch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Scotty: while it's been long time since I don't use MySQL myself, I do think MySQL is a mature database capable of handling huge amounts of transactions and offer excellent security.

I just saw mwan100 answer and I think is right on the money: you should stick to what you know now and plan for the foreseeable future and not beyond.

Comment: Good points. thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is used by almost all hosting providers in the world. So that should give you some idea of why MySQL should be seriously considered. And then I agree - plan for the forseeable future only and not beyond.

Comment: Good point. thanks for your response.